# Hibernate working on local machine but failing on Heroku

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, heroku

so i recently deployed my application on Heroku but when i try to add hibernate connection to a database it fails. I added JawsDB as an Add-on to my heroku application and connect to it with this hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://ehc1u4pmphj917qf.cbetxkdyhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/ycm07x7z21h40k84</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">ycm07x7z21h40k84</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My Hibernate configuration class is the following:

```
public class HibernateUtils {
  private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  static {
    try {
      Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

      configuration.addAnnotatedClass(City.class);
      ...
      configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Review.class);

      StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
              .applySettings(
                      configuration.getProperties())
              .build();

      sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("----------------------");
      System.out.println(ex);
    }
  }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

And after that i wire the SessionFactory as a bean and it gets provided as a dependency where i need it. Everything works when i compile it and run it locally but when i deploy it to Heroku the following error occurs:

```
2018-12-11T18:52:35.687631+00:00 app[web.1]: ----------------------
2018-12-11T18:52:35.687723+00:00 app[web.1]: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
2018-12-11T18:52:35.692621+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-12-11 18:52:35.692  WARN 4 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usersService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dbProfileService' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/build/libs/build_3eb7c290daa3670885240cb93ab898a5-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/squadknowhow/services/DbProfileService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'provideUsersGenericRepository' defined in class path resource [squadknowhow/configurations/AppConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'provideUsersGenericRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2018-12-11T18:52:35.696062+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-12-11 18:52:35.695  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-12-11T18:52:36.049747+00:00 app[web.1]: 2018-12-11 18:52:36.049  WARN 4 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
2018-12-11T18:52:36.539830+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-12-11T18:52:36.557418+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I am absolutely sure that the username and the password are valid. I have connected to the database with MySQL Workbench successfully with that information. I suspect that i have to configure Hibernate additionally in order to use it on Heroku but unfortunately i wasn't able to find a tutorial for my case. If you want more information i am more than happy to provide it. If you can point me in the right direction it will also be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you're using obsolete configuration instead of Spring Boot and the Hibernate JPA personality?

Comment: I am using it because in the courses about Spring MVC and Hibernate they showed me to configure it like that and it has been working until now.

Comment: should i be using Spring Boot and Hibernate JPA?

Comment: That would be my recommendation. It appears that you're using resources targeted at Hibernate 3; the current version is 5.3. With Spring Boot, the only thing you'd have to do is provide the JDBC connection URL (username/password included or separately), and Boot can autodetect it from both Heroku and Cloud Foundry if it's bound to the application. The entire rest of this setup would happen automatically. (It would also be better to use JPA APIs, Spring `@Transactional`, and Spring Data JPA if you have the option.)

Comment: Can you pls point me to a good tutorial on how to migrate or setup it.

Comment: First Google result: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the problem is that Heroku cannot find hibernate.cfg.xml file but at the same time the configuration java file needs it. The solution was to configure hibernate without the hibernate.cfg.xml file, which i found from this website how to do: https://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/configure_hibernate_without_hibernate_cfg_xml

Comment: Thanks! Got same problem and your solution still works.

Answer (score 0):

You should place your cfg file in `src/main/resources` or you can tell the configure absolute path of cfg file like this:

`configuration.configure("/*{PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE}*/hibernate.cfg.xml");`

(The first one is better.)

Comment: I am not sure that i understand what you mean by placing my cfg file in the resources folder. If i move it to the resources how am i going to reference this file in order to get the SessionFactory.

Comment: If you can't change your file location you can set the path of cfg file when you call `Configure` (as I said in second way in my answer).